# How to JPA Query for Postgresql @Type list-array?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have column in a database in which data are stored in this way {type1,type2,...}. I want to get elements from CARS table which are in Set carTypes.

```java
 @Type(type = "list-array")
 @Column(name = "TYPES")
 private final List<String> types;
```

Not working:

```java
@Query("SELECT * FROM cars c WHERE (:carTypes) IN (c.types)")
List<Object[]> findCars(@Nullable @Param("carTypes") Set<String> carTypes);
```

Error:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bytea = character varying[]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the Spring Data abstraction for this (or if there is any), but with plain Hibernate you can do something like this:

```java
BasicType type = (BasicType) session.getFactory()
    .getMappingMetamodel()
    .getEntityDescriptor(Car.class)
    .getPropertyType("types");
List<Car> list = session.createQuery(
      "SELECT * FROM cars c WHERE (:carTypes) IN (c.types)",
      Car.class
    )
    .setParameter("carTypes", carTypes, type)
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: I used postgresql array operator '&&' and native query :) Problem solved